# php fopen: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403

Tags: file-io, php

I am receiving an error message in PHP 5 when I try to open a file of a different website. So the line

```
fopen("http://www.domain.com/somef­ile.php", r)
```

returns an error

> Warning: fopen(www.domain.com/somefile.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in D:\xampp\htdocs\destroyfiles\index.php on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP app failed to authenticate. The request URI should be:

```
http://user:password@www.domain.com/somefile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PHP client (i.e. the server on which your PHP script is running) isn't allowed to get `http://www.domain.com/somef­ile.php`, by the server on `www.domain.com`.

Comment: Either that or his local network is on a proxy and PHP isn't authorizing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, access with curl works fine. But with php and fopen, I got an http 403

```
192.168.1.144 - "GET /dop007.pdf HTTP/1.0" 403 392 "-" "-"
192.168.1.144 - "GET /dop007.pdf HTTP/1.1" 302 430 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
```

I could fix the issue with changing the HTTP Version to 1.1

```
$context = stream_context_create([
        'http'=>[
                'protocol_version' => 1.1
        ]
]);

if ($file = fopen($filePath, 'rb',false,$context)) {
    while ( ! feof($file) and (connection_status() == 0)) {
        print(fread($file, 1024 * 8));
        flush();
    }
    fclose($file);
} else {
    Log::error('Search Request Failed');
}
```